# Visual Studio 2019 Community | There is already a command handler for the menu command '5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819 : 26'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So recently I've been developing some Office Add-Ins in Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I've been using the VSTO version with Visual Basic as the corresponding language.

Everything worked for most of the time, until someday random errors kept popping up:
***"There is already a command handler for the menu command '5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819 : 26'"***

Things I've tried so far (as I've already googled a lot):

1. Reinstall Visual Studio
2. Remove my only installed package (VS PowerPacks), but didnt change anything, error still occured
3. Changed target CPU
4. Reset Visual Studio settings
5. Created a new project with everything reset

**But none of those things changed anything and I'm not sure why.**

As of now, my project is made out of 3 main files

**1. The standard ThisAddIn.vb**

```
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub
```

**2. My Ribbon1.vb file**

```
    Dim UCPane As UserControl1
    Private taskPane As CustomTaskPane

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        UCPane = New UserControl1
        taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(UCPane, "Title formatter")
        taskPane.Width = 500
        taskPane.Visible = True

    End Sub
```

**3. And lastly, my UserControl1.vb**
(Only posting the code when necessary as I think it hasn't to do anything with the UserControl1.vb code, because the Add-In worked fine with the same code a couple of days ago)

---

The following message is shown, when I'm trying to access my Ribbon1 via Visual Designer:

```
at System.ComponentModel.Design.MenuCommandService.AddCommand(MenuCommand command)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.BehaviorService.MenuCommandHandler.System.ComponentModel.Design.IMenuCommandService.AddCommand(MenuCommand command)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.CommandSet..ctor(ISite site)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCommandSet..ctor(ISite site)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.DocumentDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.Design.RibbonDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Serialization.TypeResolutionModifications.VSTDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.Serialization.RibbonTypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

And sadly, I'm not quite sure yet on how to reproduce this error. My only clue would've been that Visual Studio doesnt like the VS PowerPacks, but as I've said, even removing the rectangle or line shapes I included, changed nothing.

If I should post the designer files extra, tell me.

It would be great, if someone has some tipps and things that I should and could do better.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't want to quote the entire non-SO post, so have you seen [www.windows-tech.info/3/742e68d8fde9e802.php](http://www.windows-tech.info/3/742e68d8fde9e802.php)?

Comment: Yes, I've been on that site before, but I'm not really not sure how to do that. I've never implemented any of those lines and dont know where to check if they've been generated automatically

Comment: Does [MenuCommandService.FindCommand Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.menucommandservice.findcommand) give you somewhere to start from?

Comment: Nothing for now..

Comment: I removed the VB6 tag which seemed to be added here by mistake? Was there a reason for it?

Comment: Is [this reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9f7caf1-7b93-4d20-9b56-1574257c8010/there-is-already-a-command-handler-for-the-menu-command) helpful?

Comment: Already tried that one. There's no += in any of my designer code (UserForm, Ribbon etc.)